# Question on the first fundamental form

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, hamiltonian-formalism

The first fundamental form is related to the metric tensor of the manifold as follows:

$$h_{ab} = g_{ab} - \sigma \text{ } n_a n_b$$

Where $\sigma$ is +1 or -1 depending on normalization of the normal vector, and $n_a$ is the component of the normal vector. As I understand it, the first fundamental form is of the same dimensionality as the metric tensor with each of the indices running from 1 to n. However, some people refer to the first fundemental form as the pullback of the metric on to the surface. This implies that the form is of dimensionality $n-1$. What is the relation between these two definitions?

In addition, we define the lapse function and the shift vector as the following respectively:

$$N^a = h^a_bt^b$$ and $$N = -g_{ab}t^an^b$$
Where $n^b$ is the normal to the hypersurface, and $t^a$ is some vector field on the manifold. How do we arrive at the following relation between the determinants of the metrics?

$$\sqrt{-g} = N\sqrt{h} $$
Where $N$ is the lapse function and $g$ and $h$ are the determinants of the metric and the first fundamental form respectively.

Comment: Another way of  looking at this, is that $h_{ab}$ is a projection operator ($h_{a}{}^{c}h_{cb} = h_{ab}$, and has three nonzero eigenvalues and one zero eigenvalue, so in the basis where you have one row and one column that have all zero values, you can say that it's isomorphic with the $n-1$ metric

Answer (score 2):

As a matrix, $h_{\mu\nu}$ has the same dimensionality as $g_{\mu\nu}$, but it's rank is $n-1$. To see this, we note
$$
h_{\mu\nu} n^\nu = n_\mu - \sigma n^2 n_\mu = 0
$$
since $n^2 = \sigma$. The first fundamental form is strictly defined as
$$
h_{ab} = e_a^\mu e_b^\nu h_{\mu\nu}  , \qquad e_a^\mu =\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^a} . 
$$
where $y^a$ is any intrinsic choice of coordinates on the hypersurface $\Sigma$. Notice here that $\mu,\nu=0,\cdots,d-1$ whereas $a,b=1\cdots,d-1$. $h_{\mu\nu}$ is not an invertible matrix, but $h_{ab}$ is!

The lapse and shift is defined as
$$
N^a = h^{ab} e^\mu_b t_\mu , \qquad N = - n^\mu t_\mu.
$$

In terms of the lapse and shift, the metric takes the form
$$
ds^2 = - N^2 dt^2 + h_{ab} ( dy^a + N^a dt ) ( dy^b + N^b dt ).
$$
So in matrix form, we have
$$
g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
- N^2 + h_{ab} N^a N^b  & h_{bc} N^c \\ h_{ac} N^c & h_{ab}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
To find the determinant, we can use row operations on this matrix. We replace the first row with $R_0 \to R_0 - N^1 R_1 - N^2 R_2 - \cdots - N^{d-1} R_{d-1}$. The determinant is invariant under row operations so we have
\begin{align}
\det ( g_{\mu\nu} ) &= \det \begin{pmatrix}
- N^2 + h_{ab} N^a N^b - N^a ( h_{ac} N^c )  & h_{bc} N^c - N^a ( h_{ab} ) \\ h_{ac} N^c & h_{ab}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \det \begin{pmatrix}
- N^2  & 0 \\ h_{ac} N^c & h_{ab}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
We can further simplify (though its not really necessary) by doing column operations $C_0 \to C_0 - N^1 C_1 - N^2 C_2 - \cdots - N^{d-1} C_{d-1}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\det ( g_{\mu\nu} ) &= \det \begin{pmatrix}
- N^2  & 0 \\ 0 & h_{ab}
\end{pmatrix} = - N^2 \det (h_{ab} ) .
\end{align}
We therefore have
$$
g = - N^2 h \quad \implies \quad \sqrt{-g} = N \sqrt{h}.
$$

Comment: I see, so if the first fundamental form $h_{ab}$ is defined as the pullback of $h_{ab}$, what is $h_{ab}$ called? It is mentioned as the fundamental form in Sean Caroll General relativity.  Also, is the reason why it is rank $n-1$ because it has a 1-D null space? I am also unsure whether I understand its components well. In components, do we have $h_{0 \nu} = h_{\mu 0} = 0$?

Comment: The first fundamental form $h_{ab}$ is the pull back of $g_{\mu\nu}$. $h_{\mu\nu}$ (not $h_{ab}$) has rank $n-1$ because it has a 1D null space spanned by $n^\mu$. It's specific components are coordinate dependent so you can't make general statements, but if I were to work in the $(t,y^a)$ coordinates, then $h_{tt} = h_{ta} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $X$ is an $n$ dimensional spacetime manifold with metric tensor $g$, and $\Sigma$ is a hypersurface ($n-1$ dimensional embedded submanifold) in $X$ with $\phi:\Sigma\rightarrow X$ being the embedding. We further suppose that $\Sigma$ is pseudo-Riemannian in the sense that the pullback metric $h=\phi^\ast g$ is nondegenerate.

The usual argument shows that there exists (we assume both $X$ and $\Sigma$ are orientable) a normal 1-form $n$ along $\Sigma$ which satisfies $g(n,n)=\sigma$ and is unique up to sign. If $n^\sharp$ is the (contravariant) vector field along $\Sigma$ that corresponds to $n$ (in coordinates $n^\sharp=n^\mu\partial_\mu$ while $n=n_\mu dx^\mu$) by metric duality, then $n^\sharp$ is nowhere tangential.

We can make the following definition. Let $T$ be a tensor field of type (r,s) along $\Sigma$ (that is a smooth map $T:\Sigma\rightarrow T^{r,s}X$ which satisfies $\pi\circ T=\phi$, where $\pi:T^{r,s}X\rightarrow X$ is the bundle projection and $T^{r,s}X$ is the type (r,s) tensor bundle of $X$). We say that $T$ is *tangential* if it is true that **any** contraction of $T$ with $n$ vanishes. Let $$ T^{r,s}_\mathrm{tan}(\Sigma,X) $$ denote the subbundle of the pullback bundle $\phi^\ast T^{r,s}X$ that consists of tangential type (r,s) tensors. That is $T^{r,s}_\mathrm{tan}(\Sigma,X)$ is a vector bundle over $\Sigma$ whose elements are tangential type (r,s) tensors of $X$ whose basepoint is on $\Sigma$.

Let $T^{r,s}\Sigma$ denote the vector bundle of type (r,s) tensors of $\Sigma$.

**Theorem:** The vector bundles $T^{r,s}_\mathrm{tan}(\Sigma,X)$ and $T^{r,s}\Sigma$ are isomorphic.

This isomorphism is described in coordinates as follows. Let $x^\mu$ be a coordinate system in $X$ and $y^a$ a coordinate system in $\Sigma$. With respect to these charts the embedding functions take the form $$ x^\mu=\phi^\mu(y^1,...,y^{n-1}). $$ Let us use the notation $$ \phi^\mu_a:=\frac{\partial\phi^\mu}{\partial y^a}. $$ Using the normal we can also define a "pseudo-inverse" of this matrix as $$ \phi^a_\mu:=h^{ab}g_{\mu\nu}\phi^\nu_b. $$

if $T^{a_1...a_r}_{b_1...b_s}$ are the components of a type (r,s) tensor field defined in $\Sigma$, we define the corresponding tangential tensor field (of $X$) along $\Sigma$ by $$ T^{\mu_1...\mu_r}_{\nu_1...\nu_s}=\phi^{\mu_1}_{a_1}...\phi^{\mu_r}_{a_r}\phi^{b_1}_{\nu_1}...\phi^{b_s}_{\nu_s}T^{a_1...a_r}_{b_1...b_s}. $$ Conversely, if $T^{\mu_1...\mu_r}_{\nu_1...\nu_s}$ is a tangential tensor field of $X$ along $\Sigma$, we can define the corresponding intrinsic $\Sigma$-tensor field by $$ T^{a_1...a_r}_{b_1...b_s}= $\phi^{a_1}_{\mu_1}...\phi^{a_r}_{\mu_r}\phi^{\nu_1}_{b_1}...\phi^{\nu_s}_{b_s}T^{\mu_1...\mu_r}_{\nu_1...\nu_s}.$$

In this scheme, the projection tensor $$ h_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}-\sigma n_\mu n_\nu $$ is the tangential tensor field along $\Sigma$ corresponding to the intrinsic $\Sigma$-tensor field $$ h_{ab}=\phi^\mu_a\phi^\nu_b g_{\mu\nu}. $$